# React-Boostrap Modal not showing

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am experiencing some problems with react-bootstrap Modal, that arent showing as i would like it to.

This is the code for the modal. And the showModal and hideModal functions are of cause, setting the showModal boolean to true and false respectively.

I have `import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap` in the top of my file.

Can anyone help me out?

TIA

```html
<Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={(e)=> this.hideModal(e)}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Translations</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
        <h4>Filter:</h4>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
        <hr />
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={(e)=> this.hideModal(e)}>Close</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>

<Button className="btn btn-primary m-1" onClick={(e)=> { this.showModal(e) }}>
    See modal
</Button>
```

Comment: Where are the showModal, hideModal functions? react-bootstrap doesn't yet support Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Not yet familiar with modals, but does it help using this.setState({showModal: true}); on your onClick?

Comment: Hmm. It might be, that i started out with Bootstrap 4. But i just ran `npm install bootstrap@3.3.7` and still nothing is working.

Comment: @OliverJuhl could you check your modal's z-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`show`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-props) prop is taking boolean. When `true` The modal will show itself. So inside of your handler you need to set state `true/false`.

You can check here with working **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-boostrap-modal-not-showing)** demo.

**Code Snippet**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

//Presentational Components MyModel
const MyModel = (props) => (<Modal show={props.isHidden} onHide={props.onClose}>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Translations</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    <h4>Filter:</h4>
    <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
    <hr />
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button onClick={props.onClose}>Close</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    }
  }

  showModal = (e) => {
    this.setState({ showModal: true })
  }

  hideModal = (e) => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyModel isHidden={this.state.showModal} onClose={this.hideModal} />
        <Button className="btn btn-primary m-1" onClick={this.showModal}>Show modal</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I've done this exact thing. And my does not work. It's just a transparent div for me.

Comment: could you please create [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) demo so I can try to check issue.